# A simple analog neural network to implement the XOR operation

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, diodes, analog, bidirectional

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01981.pdf) and wanted to replicate some of the results as part of a learning process. I'm more of a digital guy but obviously have had some analog design as part of my studies.

Implementing a neural network model to learn the XOR operation is quite easy in Python, for example. In the analog domain, you have to worry about (1) how to multiply the activations with the weights (2) how to add the result (3) how to apply a non-linear function to the sum (4) how to propagate the errors from the output to the inputs (5) ensure that the amplitude does not degrade as it flows through the network in both directions.

The paper I mentioned above offers a solution to the above problem in the form of the block diagram shown below:

[image]

1. Multiplication and addition is done using a resistive array. This is straight-forward to do (for just the inference).
2. A sigma non-linearity is applied using a diodes.
3. Bidirectional amplifiers ensure that the signal quality is maintained in both directions.
4. A current source at the output injects some current into the network in proportion to the error. This is only done during training.

The author of the paper did the analog simulation for inference in SPICE, read-out the results in Python, computed the error in Python, applied a current in proportion to the error, and allowed the circuit to run again in SPICE.

The result of the implementation of the XOR operation is shown below:

[image]

I would like to replicate the results for the system shown above. Even though I have taken a few courses in analog electronics, they have been focused more towards theory and my analog design skills are not great.

My main question is designing the neuron as shown in the first image. How do I design the non-linearity and bidirectional amplifier ?

Comment: Replicate in practise or SPICE?

Comment: SPICE. I don't think it's that easy to replicate in practice due to the need for reprogrammable resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper has an appendix where they name the elements they used and a few other details. I'll just focus on your question:

> How do I design the non-linearity and bidirectional amplifier ?

For the nonlinearity, they added two anti-parallel diodes with voltage sources for pre-polarization. For diodes, appendix `C.2` gives `Is=1u` and `n=2`, so you can add a diode with this `.model` card:

```
.model D D Is=1u n=2 ; Rs=10m Cjo=10p
```

The extra `Rs` and `Cjo` are minor additions that can help with convergence or with possible unwanted oscillations, if needed (just uncomment them by removing the `;`). `Rs` is mostly to have a series resistance (damping), and `Cjo` helps by smoothing out sharp derivatives to a sufficiently small transition. As I said, "if". The sources are given as `0.3 V` and `-0.7 V`.

The VCVS-CCCS pair is known as an "ideal transformer", or a "DC transformer", and it acts like an inductorless transformer: the load draws current from the VCVS, and the CCCS takes that back to the source. And "DC" because it will happily deliver DC.

The whole "nonlinear amplifier" looks like this (the values for `V1` and `I1` are random):

[image: amp]

I wanted to recreate the example on page 29, but they are using iterations to reach those values and the output currents are not shown. That's not something you can just throw in values in there and hope to work, so that's a part for another day.

Comment: Something that I forgot to add: in the picture they're showing the controlling wire terminated in a small circle, similar to a negated input in logic. I don't know if that's what they meant, so it's something to determine.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, thanks very much for the reply. I was actually giving it a shot myself. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/wlTbWKc.png). As you can see, I tried making the amplifier slightly more realistic by adding the input and output impedances. I simulated the circuit but did not get the same result as the one in the paper. I feel there's an issue with the antiparallel diodes. To make it approximate a sigmoid (limited to the range 0<x<1), the values should be +0.3 and +0.7, not -0.7. I might have to retrain the model to get my own set of resistances. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @ChadWinters If you want soft limiting to [0,1] then your best bet would be the `tanh()` function, or the [undocumented](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#B-Sources) `uplim()` and `dnlim()`. You can either use a behavioural source, or (IMHO) the beter choice: `[SpecialFunctions]/ota` (see in the same link). I don't know if having a "more realistic output" is what the model is supposed to have, but I admit I haven't ran with a fine toothed comb through the paper, so I don't feel particularly motivated to go into the nitty-gritty details of modelling this.